# Why is this unsafeCoerce not unsafe?

Tags: haskell, ghc

Some library use `unsafeCoerce` to temporarily satisfy constraint:

```
class Given a where given :: a

newtype Gift a r = Gift (Given a => r)

give :: forall a r. a -> (Given a => r) -> r
give a k = unsafeCoerce (Gift k :: Gift a r) a
```

(This example is from [reflection](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/reflection-2.1.4/docs/src/Data.Reflection.html#Given) package.
[singletons](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/singletons-2.5.1/docs/src/Data.Singletons.Internal.html#singInstance) package also uses this trick.)

Why is this `unsafeCoerce` safe?
Is there any official document which guarantee that `Given a => r` and `a -> r` have the same runtime representation in GHC?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No official document guarantees it. Ed Kmett is relying on what he knows about the inner workings of GHC. What he knows:

1. In GHC Core, `->` and `=>` actually mean the same thing.
2. Dictionaries for instances of single-method classes without superclasses are erased like newtypes—the dictionary *is* the method.

I've actually written a [proposal](https://github.com/ghc-proposals/ghc-proposals/pull/69) to try to do this legitimately, but it's tricky to accommodate all the use cases properly.